# Git merge into appropriate subdirectory

Tags: git, merge

Given the following Git branch structures, is it possible to merge a specific commit from *master branch* into *v5 branch* although the folder nesting level has changed?

*"master" branch*

```
Folder A
-- Folder B
  -- File X
  -- File Y
```

*"v5" branch*

```
Folder B
-- File X
-- File Y
```

I've already tried simple merging and cherry picking but I'm pretty new to Git, so both workflows are resulting in duplicate directories because the hierarchies do not fit to each other:

*Result after merge*

```
Folder B
-- Folder A (from master)
  -- Folder B (from master)
    -- File X (from master)
    -- File Y (from master)
-- File X
-- File Y
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Something isn't right here, because the line `-- Folder A (from master)` appears in _neither_ of the two files, and Git's merge tool won't alter the original text from either of the two sources.  You might want to check your data.

Comment: Do the branches/files share a common history? If the files _do not_ share a common history, it will be pretty difficult for git to pick up that the files were moved on one of the two branches.

Comment: You're describing the result of `git merge` as though it has just two inputs: branch name `master` and branch name `v5`. But `git merge` has *three* inputs, and all of them are actually *commit hash IDs:* the two branch names are translated to their tip commits, and then Git finds a third commit that is shared in the history reachable from both of these two commits. The merge then works by using the *base* commit, comparing it to each tip to find who changed what, and combining the two sets of changes.